# Deleting rows containing any number outside a specific range - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What is the best way to delete rows of a matrix containing a number outside a specific range? For example

```
A =

200  400
500  200
500  100
600  200
200  100
300  200

Range = [200 500];
```

Rows 3,4 and 5 would then be deleted as they contain numbers <200 and >500.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you -

```
A(any(A<200 | A>500,2),:)=[];
```

To state that generally -

```
range1 = [200 500]; %// changed the variable name as 
                    %// range is already a builtin function name
A(any(A<range1(1) | A>range1(2),2),:)=[];
```

If the number of rows to be deleted is a lot, for performance you might as well index into the other rows instead of deleting -

```
range1 = [200 500];
A = A(~any(A<range1(1) | A>range1(2),2),:)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be:

```
A(any(A<200 | A>500,2),:) = [];
```

Comment: What empty cells? Assigning rows of a matrix to empty simply removes them.

Comment: How is this different from Divakar's first solution?  No offense intended.  I am just curious.

Comment: No different. Cannot blame people for typing it together i guess.